# Pass extra parameter to custom actions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi I have a custom action in my viewset, but beyond detail=True, Im not sure how to add more arguments to the route I want to make an action to filter doctors from a certain category, the url should be something like `doctor/categories/<int:category_id>` but Im getting a Page not found (404) when trying to add the argument

```
  @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def categories(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        """ 
        Get a list of doctor profiles from an specific category 
        """


        data = {
            'profile' : 'doctor',
        }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

EDIT--

when trying something like this

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='categories/<int:category_id>')
    def categories(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
```

Im still getting error 404 and when checking the available routes I find this

```
v1/ ^profiles/doctors/categories/<int:category_id>/$ [name='profiles/doctors-categories']

v1/ ^profiles/doctors/categories/<int:category_id>\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='profiles/doctors-categories']
```

So the url is there... but maybe somehow Im typing it wrong?

this is my url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/profiles/doctors/categories/1
```

This is my urls.py (simplyfied)

```
from sanitas.views import doctor_schedule as doctor_schedule_views

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'profiles/doctors', doctor_profiles_views.DoctorProfileViewset, basename='profiles/doctors')


urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I hope you guys can help me

Answer (score 14):

From the DRF doc of [**Routing for extra actions**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions)

> By default, the URL pattern is based on the method name, and the URL
>   name is the combination of the ViewSet.basename and the hyphenated
>   method name. If you don't want to use the defaults for either of these
>   values, you can instead provide the `url_path` and `url_name` arguments to
>   the `@action` decorator.

So, use **`url_path`** as,

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path=r'categories/(?P<category_id>\d+)')
def categories(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return Response({'msg': 'ok', 'kwargs': kwargs})
```

Now use the end-point: **`/profiles/doctors/categories/1234/`**

**Note:** the **`url_path`** value must be in a regex compatible string, DRF won't recognise if it is a [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) compatible string

Comment: Is not working I made this
`@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='categories/<int:category_id>')`

but when going to the url `/profiles/doctors/categories/1 `

I got a Page not found (404)

And when looking at available urls I find this

` v1/ ^profiles/doctors/categories/<int:category_id>/$ [name='profiles/doctors-categories'] ` and this
` v1/ ^profiles/doctors/categories/<int:category_id>\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='profiles/doctors-categories']  `

Not sure what it means tho.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: how do you binding the URLs? Can you show your urls.py? @AnibalCardozo

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I just edited my original post to include the urls.py

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, now updated the answer with more details @pppery

Comment: how can we write regex for ```category_id``` if it is in ```uuid.uuid4()```? @ArakkalAbu

Comment: oh found it https://gist.github.com/luzfcb/186ee28b368450035e056228615db999

Answer (score 7):

you need to change your url_path value to

```
url_path=r'categories/(?P<category_id>\d+)'
```

instead of

```
url_path=r'categories/<category_id>)'
```

and you need  `category_id` parameter in your action

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path=r'categories/(?P<category_id>\d+)')
def categories(self, request,category_id, *args, **kwargs):
#here you can access your category_id param
return Response(...)
```